# Is it required to knock on doors before entering?

Tags: halacha, minhag, derech-eretz-manners

Do we have to knock on people's doors before entering?

Comment: You might add in to the question what motivated it.

Answer (score 13):

[This *g'mara*](http://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%A4%D7%A1%D7%97%D7%99%D7%9D_%D7%A7%D7%99%D7%91_%D7%90) says one should not enter anyone's home suddenly (relevant bold part translated):

> **ת"ר: שבעה דברים צוה ר"ע את רבי יהושע בנו**: "בני',
>   אל תשב בגובהה של עיר ותשנה ואל תדור בעיר שראשיה תלמידי חכמים **ואל תכנס לביתך פתאום כ"ש לבית חבירך** ואל תמנע מנעלים מרגליך השכם ואכול בקיץ מפני החמה ובחורף "מפני הצינה ועשה שבתך חול ואל תצטרך לבריות והוי משתדל עם אדם שהשעה משחקת לו
>
> Our rabbis taught: R' Akiva taught his son Rabbi Y'hoshu'a 7 things: ". . . and don't enter your house suddenly - all the more so someone else's house. . ."

I believe there is a *midrash* that states this warning in even stronger terms [citation needed].

Answer (score 12):

The Gemara in [Nida 16b](http://hebrewbooks.org/shas.aspx?mesechta=37&daf=16b&format=pdf) says that entering without informing someone is an act that Hashem hates (even in one's own house).

Answer (score 4):

I suggest that it is "acting similarly to G-d", or the mitzvah of V'Halachta B'Drachav. The verse states ([Devarim 32:11](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9996#showrashi=true&v=11))

> כְּנֶשֶׁר יָעִיר קִנּוֹ

and ([Devarim 33:2](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/9997#showrashi=true&v=2))

> ה' מִסִּינַי בָּא
>   וְזָרַח מִשֵּׂעִיר לָמוֹ הוֹפִיעַ
>   מֵהַר פָּארָן וְאָתָה מֵרִבְבֹת קֹדֶשׁ

from where we derive (see Rashi) that it is G-d's practice to not appear suddenly, but gradually and with fair warning.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, as above.

Also, I believe that the Torah's directive re the kohein gadol, venishma kolo bivo'o el hakodesh, are cited in this regard.

Comment: Correct - see Rashi to Pesachim 112a citing Midrah Raba.